# Shiny app session cookie is not found the first time

Tags: r, cookies, shiny

I am using cookies in my shiny app. But there is the problem that after a cookie is set in the browser and the page is refreshed, the cookie is not found at first. You can see this in the example app: After clicking login a cookie with value 'admin' is set. When clicking refresh the observer checking for cookies is triggered twice: The first time no cookie is found, only on the second time the cookie is then found. What is wrong with my implementation?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode <- '
  shinyjs.getcookie = function(params) {
    var cookie = Cookies.get("id");
    if (typeof cookie !== "undefined") {
      Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", cookie);
    }
  }
  shinyjs.setcookie = function(params) {
    Cookies.set("id", escape(params), { expires: 0.5 });
    Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", params);
  }
  shinyjs.rmcookie = function(params) {
    Cookies.remove("id");
    Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", "");
  }
  shinyjs.reload = function() {
    history.go(0);
  }
'


ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js")
  ),
  uiOutput("ui"),
  actionButton("login", "login"),
  actionButton("logout", "logout"),
  actionButton("reload", "reload page")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    user <- reactiveVal(NULL)

    observe({
      output$ui <- renderUI({
        h1(paste0("Hello ", user()))
      })
    })

    observe({
      print("Checking for cookie")
      js$getcookie()
      print(input$jscookie)
      if (!is.null(input$jscookie) && input$jscookie != "") {
        print("Cookie found")
        user(input$jscookie)
      } else {
        print("No cookie found")
        user(NULL)
      }
    })

  observeEvent(input$login, {
    print("login")
    js$setcookie("admin")
  })

  observeEvent(input$logout, {
    print("logout")
    js$rmcookie()
  })

  observeEvent(input$reload, {
    print("refresh")
    js$reload()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: No Computer at hand but you try to have a look at document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",..so waiting till page is fully loaded,..

Comment: @TonioLiebrand Can you provide an example on how to use the `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded")` in this case? I am still struggling to solve this problem.

Comment: is the accepted answer not working anymore?

Comment: It works for the reprex I provided, but my actual problem is actually a bit different than this reprex. So maybe I create a new question for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The observe function is triggered firstly when the input variable `jscookie` is created by your shiny application. In this case `jscookie` is still `NULL`. Adding the `js$getcookie()` before printing `input$jscookie` doesn't change that because the assignment happens at the end of your `observer`.

The second trigger happens after you applied the function `js$getcookie()`. In this case a cookie is found.

You can avoid the double trigger by using an `observeEvent(...)` function and adding the `getcookie()` function outside the `observer`. Now the function is executed before the observer is executed.

```
js$getcookie()
  observeEvent(input$jscookie, {
    print("Checking for cookie")
    print(input$jscookie)
    if (!is.null(input$jscookie) && input$jscookie != "") {
      print("Cookie found")
      user(input$jscookie)
    } else {
      print("No cookie found")
      user(NULL)
    }
  })
```